# Show on string not id function?

Tags: haskell

Could someone explain to me why the **show** function on string is not **id** function?  For  example

`show (show 42)` will return `"\"42\""` what is weird and for me not intitutive.

Comment: And wait till you try `show (show (show 42))` :P

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`show` isn't very useful if it just converts something into an arbitrary string (like `toString` in Java). It is much more useful if the result is *both* easy to read and machine-readable, so a common use of `show` is to produce a serialized representation of the value that you are `show`ing, so that you can read it in again using `read`, and also, for most implementations of `show`, so that you can type the string that is `show`n at a Haskell REPL like `ghci` and get the deserialized value back.

So, if you have a string like `"42"`, and `show` it, you want to get the string `"\"42\""`, because when you type `42` in `ghci` (and equivalently using the `read` function), you get a number, while when you type `"42"` in `ghci`, you get the string that you want.

Comment: `show` has **exactly** the purpose of converting values to Strings. Likewise the purpose of `read` is to convert Strings to values. These are stated in the Haskell Report. There is no obligation whatsoever to roundtrip. Certainly round tripping has strong merit, but it is not the purpose of Show / Read and an implementation of Show could favour say "legibility" instead.

Comment: Hmm, I guess that you're right, I'll alter the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

Because `read` is the inverse of `show`.  So I should always be able to `read` the result of `show`, and get back a String.

```
> (read "42")::String
"*** Exception: Prelude.read: no parse
> (read "\"42\"")::String
"42"
```

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question though -- why doesn't `read "42" :: String` give `"42"`?   (Not actually asking, but this was the unanswered question in your response)

Comment: I'd say same reason `let foo = bar` at the ghci prompt doesn't result in assigning the literal string "bar" to `foo`

Comment: you seem to be assuming some things about `read` which are not obvious.

Comment: The Haskell 2010 Report backs this up, sort of. "`readsPrec` should be able to parse the string produced by `showsPrec`, and should deliver the value that `showsPrec` started with." ~ [Derived instances of Read and Show](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch11.html#x18-18600011.4). At the end of the day, the answer is simply "because that's what they decided in the Haskell Report".